# AFNetworking - AFHTTPRequestOperationManager does not return data

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking

I am using `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` for login.

```
- (IBAction)loginAction
{
    [TGProjectHandler clearCookies];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"Email": _email.text,
                             @"Password": _password.text,
                             @"IsRemember": @"true",
                             @"ReturnUrl": @"",
                             @"UserId": @0,
                             @"OutResponse": @0};

    [_sharedHandler.requestManager POST:TGURL_LOGIN
                             parameters:params
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

     NSError *e;
     NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];                                    
      NSLog(@"%@\n\n%@", jsonDict, responseObject);
      NSString *outResponse = responseObject[@"Object"][@"OutResponse"];
      if (outResponse.integerValue == 1){
         NSLog(@"login successful: %@", outResponse);
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"User_Logged_In"];
         [TGProjectHandler saveCookiesToDefaults];
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HomePage" sender:self];
       }else
        {
           [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:@"Invalid credentials" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
     }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         [TGProjectHandler dismissHUD];
         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
       }];
}
```

The service function returns UserID, but this is what I am getting in response while `NSLog`.

```
NSLog(@"%@\n\n%@", jsonDict, responseObject); 



Object =     {
        OutResponse = 1;
        ReturnUrl = "<null>";
    };
    Success = 1;
}

{
    Object =     {
        OutResponse = 1;
        ReturnUrl = "<null>";
    };
    Success = 1;
}
```

Why is **UserId** not coming in response?

Comment: i think u passed the mismatch data

Comment: May be your server is not returning USERID becasuse of your request may be not InValid

Comment: Always check your request in the REST first. Then, go back to your code. You have to address where the problem is.

Comment: But then why am I getting OutResponse as 1 ?

Comment: I tried the same request using NSURLConnection. It works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code I guess the problem might be content type in your request. Check if your content type is set properly.

For Example -

```
[_sharedHandler.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Also you can change response serializer to AFJSONResponseSerializerwhich will automatically convert your response to dictionary or array.

```
_sharedHandler.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```